# why the (if) condition is not satisfied, but the function is working?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

The code is below. When the variate **i*dx** is equal to 140, this would not meet the condition, but why cout works? ***if I changed the 1.4 to 1.3 or other numbers, this weird thing does not happen.***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    double dx = 0.01;
    float ip = 1.4;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    {
        if(  (i*dx > ip)   &&   (abs(i*dx - ip) > 0)    &&   (i*dx < 1.6)  )
        {
            cout << "i = " << i << endl;
            cout << "i*dx = " << i*dx << endl;
            printf("printf. i*dx = %f \n", i*dx);   
            printf("printf. ip = %0.10f \n", ip);   
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[now, problem solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbxIf.png)

Comment: To explain the duplicate: float 1.4 is probably ever so slightly larger than 1.4.

Comment: Try rewriting `(i*dx > 1.4)` to `(i*dx > 1.4 + 0.0000001)`. I.e. add small epsilon value.

Comment: I just want to know why this inaccuracy happens.

Comment: The linked duplicate explains why it happens. In your case it's not 0.1 but 1.4, but neither can be expressed as a finite binary fraction. You also have to consider what type a literal 1.4 is in C (either float or double, I don't know). In either case you have the same situation as the linked question. Expecting floating-point values to have exact values leads to surprises. You have to account for some tolerance in your code.

Comment: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html shows that the closest representable value to 1.4 is 11740551*(2^-23) = 1.39999997615814208984375

Comment: Right, I messed up my directions. If `> 1.4` is unexpectedly tripped it means that the float 1.4 is _smaller_ than 1.4. That, and `i*dx` might be larger than 1.4 (I'm not any good at float arithmetic).

Comment: thanks very much! very helpful! I understood!